# What is the meaning of the apparently runic symbol carved on (former Nazi agriculture minister and SS officer) Walther Darré's grave?

Tags: runes

What is the meaning of this apparently runic symbol carved on the grave of Walther Darré, the former Nazi agriculture minister and high-ranking SS officer? Darré was found guilty on some of the charges made against him at Nuremburg, was released from jail in 1950, and died in 1953.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It looks like a compound rune.  Two symbols used by the SS.  But also a few more.

According to the chart, looks like **D. Ger-Rune** with **F. Wolfsangel (variant)** crossing over the middle line of the former rune, making the **X** mark.  Then you would get  the rune in the picture you shown.

[image]

[image source](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/416653403006021633/)

Walther Darré is a high ranking SS officer, so it would make sense with the **Wolfsangel** rune in there.  **Ger** would also make sense, as an interpretation of it means "successful harvest," which would be a nod to his position as agricultural minister.

In addition, there is also a solar symbol in their as well, the circle with a cross (Sun Cross)... with the circle being a snake biting it's own tail (Ouroboros).  Perhaps a nod to Jörmungandr, the giant serpent in Norse mythology.  All enclosed in a Shield.

Seems like a symbol customized for Walther Darré, signifying his importance.